# QTableView no row area's signal

Tags: signals, qtableview

Is there a way to detect when a QTableView is clicked in the area with no rows?Does QTableView emit any signals?No one of the 7 signals described on the Qt documentation page is emitted unless a row has been clicked.I Need to know that because on that event selected rows are deselected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by catching the signal

```
selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)
```

emitted by the model tied to the tableview;